# How can I perform a function each time that the user select a specific value into a select dropdown using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-events

I am pretty new in jQuery and I have the following problem.

Into a page I have this HTML code:

```
<div>
    <label>Regioni:</label>
    <select id="selReg">
        <option value="AB">ABRUZZO</option>
        <option value="BA">BASILICATA</option>
        <option value="CA">CAMPANIA</option>
        <option value="CL">CALABRIA</option>
        ........................................
        ........................................
        ........................................
    </select>
</div>
```

Then in the same page I am trying to create a jQuery script that do something when the user select an option of the previous select, I done in this way:

```
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){

            // Quando l'utente seleziona una specifica regione
            selReg.change(function() {
                alert("REGIONE SELEZIONATA");
            }

        }
    </script>
```

As you can see I am trying to perform a function (that perform the `alert();`) when the fire event on the select having `id="selReg"`. But it don't work

What am I missing? What is wrong? How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Three Issues:

1) Wrong selector to target select element.

2) Missing closing braces for change event. which causes syntax error.

3) Missing closing braces for ready event. which causes syntax error.

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
  // ISSUE1  
  $('#selReg').change(function() {
            alert("REGIONE SELEZIONATA");
  });// ISSUE2  
 });// ISSUE3
```

Answer (score 0):

you have mistake here `selReg.change(function() {` bind it with `<select>` like `$("#selReg").change(function() {`

[More Info how to use bind() method](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/event_bind.asp)

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){

        // Quando l'utente seleziona una specifica regione
        $("#selReg").change(function() {
            alert("REGIONE SELEZIONATA");
        });

    });
</script>
```

SideNote: you may also have error `SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list` because missing closing brackets `);`

Always check browser console log to debug these error.